# Project Euler #2 in c++ What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the basics of c++ by doing some euler problems.
I got stuck on problem 2, why is this code wrong?
I do know that this isn't the right way to do it (it is much to long).

The problem is:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number1 = 0, number2 = 1, sum = 0;
    long int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        if (number1 < 4000000) {
            if (number1 % 2 == 0){
                sum = sum + number1;
            }
        }
        if (number2 < 4000000) {
            if (number2 % 2 == 0) {
                sum = sum + number2;
            }
        }

        if (i % 2) {
        number1 = number2 + number1;
        }
        else {
        number2 = number1 + number2;
        }
    }

    std::cout << sum << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I know the right code but I still don't understand what is wrong with mine.
The output I need is 4613732, but I have 9227464 as output. note that this is double of what I need.

UPDATE: I updated my code but I still get double of the answer I need.
Also I am sorry for the bad question first. I updated it too.

Comment: `number1 % 2` returns an `int`. Why are you comparing with `false`?

Comment: What is your output and what should it be?

Comment: If the int = 0 then it is false and I then I know number1 is even.

Comment: Sure `false` is 0 as an `int`, but it makes no sense to do that instead of just comparing with 0.

Comment: My output is 5702886 and the output should be 4613732

Comment: Well, I changed it and now my output is 9227464.

Comment: @LorenzoDB, You might notice that 9227464 is double what you expect. Still, changing `false` to 0 should not change the output.

Comment: Indeed, but why is it?

Comment: No idea. Both print 9227464 for me.

Comment: Bottom line: you should never compare ANYTHING to a Boolean literal, not even a Boolean variable

Comment: @Josh I changed all the Boolean to integers.

Comment: @LorenzoDB then update the code in your question. Furthermore, what is this program even supposed to DO? For those of us who aren't members of the Euler community, you've just thrown a bunch of code out there and asked us to fix it (I know this is why I personally downvoted).

Comment: @Thomas it is the same because in the then clause I change number1, in the else clause I change number2

Comment: @LorenzoDB So then put all of the code that's the same BEFORE the if statement so that you don't need to be writing the same thing twice

Comment: @Josh I''ll do that tomorrow, I'm on the phone now. I'll add the instructions also. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try to run your program in the debug and figure out what goes wrong and you would know exactly where to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are double summing Fibonacci numbers, look closely in `if (i % 2)` and corresponding `else`.

Comment: I use the if (i % 2) because you need to change number1 the first time and number2 the second time. Why does it sum double then? It does one of the two, or not?

Comment: The double sum is not in the calculation of Fibonacci terms, is in the total sum. Debug, would be visible in less than 10 iterations of the loop